# How to switch context in VS.NET 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm getting build errors because some classes I'm using are available in "DNX 4.5.1" and not "DNX Core 5.0".

The error is:

> The type or namespace '[someclass]' could not be found.

In the project column of the "Error List" window, I see DNX Core 5.0.

In the context menu, DNX 4.5.1 is selected.  Why does VS.NET try to keep using DNX Core 5.0 when the context is 4.5.1?

Comment: 451 will be your projected .net framework.  It has nothing to do with any references in the project.  Check your references to make sure its only using the 451 version of your dnx.

Comment: As I mentioned, that's what the context is set to.  Are you referring to something else?

Comment: If you're seening "DNX Core 5.0" in the project column of the Error List window it sounds like you have a project called "DNX Core 5.0" as part of your Visual Studio solution.

Comment: Yes, you have a reference problem, not a context problem.  Look in your references to the project.  Have you listed "DNX Core 5.0"?  If so, remove it and only reference the 451.

Answer (score 35):

In case some people are still struggling with this, you can dereference the DNX Core 5.0 by removing it from your framework references in the project.json file.

The section

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Should become

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
```

Comment: If you're not targeting non-Windows platforms, then drop DNX Core 50 from your project.json file

Answer (score 7):

Rather than completely removing DNXCORE50 from your project.json. 
As before, you can add framework specific code if you wrap it in #if #endif as shown in the code below. The framework names DNX451 and DNXCORE50 are well known symbols actually referred to as target framework monikers (TFMs) and are the same throughout the project.json file, folder names, NuGet packages etc.

Simply apply a conditional statement:

```
public string Index(){
   #if DNX451
      //code logic here for DNX 4.5.1
   #endif
   #if DNXCORE50

      //code logic here for DNX Core 5.0

   #endif
}
```

Comment: Found you have to use this on `using` statements, in my case `using MySqlData.MySqlCLient` - was causing me grief, thanks for this.