# How to choose DNX for ASP.NET 5 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I've created an empty ASP.NET 5 project. There're two folders under References: DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0. As I have some dependencies that are not compatible with DNX Core 5.0, I'd like to use DNX 4.5.1 (my outdated dependencies are added there).

What should I do to make my project work on DNX 4.5.1? When I go to project properties, the only DNX SDK version available is 1.0.0.0-beta5 (not sure if it's related to my question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch context in VS.NET 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087232/how-to-switch-context-in-vs-net-2015)

Answer (score 2):

The 2 folders under references correspond to the targets in your `project.json` file.

Since you say you want to use `dnx451` and to use things that are not compatible with `dnxcore50` then you should remove `dnxcore50` from your `project.json` then you will see only 1 folder.